# Cache seems to be not expired after specified time in IIS 6.0

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis-6

Our application code is deployed on a production server with environment windows server 2003, iis 6.0. We have some caching code in our application to which absolute expiration is set to DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30). We used HttpContext.Current.Cache object.

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(Scope,objectCache,
                                      null,
                                      DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
                                      Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
                                      CacheItemPriority.High, LifeStyleEvicted);



private static void LifeStyleEvicted(string key, object value, CacheItemRemovedReason reason)
{
var objectCache = ((IObjectCache)value);
if (objectCache != null) objectCache.DisposeAndClear();
}
```

So after every 30 minutes cache should be restarted. All the requests in the beginning of 31st minute should take a bit longer then normal. But this behaviour is not observed yet all in windows server 2003 and IIS 6.0.

Recently we have deployed our code to windows server 2008, IIS 7.5. In this environment all the requests made at the beginning of 31st minute are taking too longer then the normal.

Can someone please tell me why this behaviour is not reproduced in windows server 2003 and IIS 6.0?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A common cause of this is application flushes (cache flushed) or web-pool restarts. If the web-pool restarts before the 30 minutes has elapsed the cache would be flushed and thus you wouldn't see any spikes at +31.

Check your event logs to see if you see any catastrophic errors on the .NET engine that would cause a process recycle, also check your recycle times on IIS to ensure that they aren't set differently.

Comment: Once we start the web-pool, we never restart it again. It runs for days on the production server. We always check event-log, no errors reported there as well. We log each request made to our production server to a file with time taken for each request. There we found this longer time to serve the requests at every 31,61,91.... minutes after starting the app.

Comment: What about recycling rather than restarting? IIS is normally set to reycle the app pool after X hours